# Creating an active dynamic Menu with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a website with a dynamic menu which changes the active menu element depending on the scrolling. I was looking at other questions similar to this one, and trying different code, but I can not resolve the problem and can not see why it is not working in my site.

I have my code like that right now: https://jsfiddle.net/49rcfg0t/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

  //smoothscroll
  $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(document).off("scroll");

    $('a').each(function () {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    })
    $(this).addClass('active');


  });
});

function onScroll(event){
  var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
  $('.topmenu a').each(function () {
    var currLink = $(this);
    var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
    if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
      $('.topmenu a').removeClass("active");
      currLink.addClass("active");
    }
    else{
      currLink.removeClass("active");
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="portfolio2.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--Menu superior-->
<nav class="header">

  <div>

    <a href="#anchor1" class="topmenu">
      <img src="http://es.seaicons.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Number-1-icon.png">
      <span id="profile">Menu 1</span>
    </a>

    <a href="#anchor2" class="topmenu">
      <img src="http://es.seaicons.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Number-2-icon.png">
      <span id="exp">Menu 2</span>
    </a>

    <a href="#anchor3" class="topmenu">
      <img src="http://es.seaicons.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Number-3-icon.png">
      <span id="hab">Menu 3</span>
    </a>

    <a href="#anchor4" class="topmenu">
      <img src="http://es.seaicons.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Number-4-icon.png">
      <span id="pro">Menu 4</span>
    </a>

    <a href="#anchor5" class="topmenu">
      <img src="http://es.seaicons.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Number-5-icon.png">
      <span id="contact">Menu 5</span>
    </a>

  </div>      

</nav>  

<div class="cuerpo">
  <span class="anchor" id="anchor1"></span>
  <div style="background-color:blue">Area 1</div>

  <span class="anchor" id="anchor2"></span>
  <div style="background-color:red">Area 2</div>

  <span class="anchor" id="anchor3"></span>
  <div style="background-color:yellow">Area 3</div>

  <span class="anchor" id="anchor4"></span>
  <div style="background-color:brown">Area 4</div>

  <span class="anchor" id="anchor5"></span>
  <div style="background-color:green">Area 5</div>
</div>
```

I have the following problems:

1. When I scroll manually the elements are not activated.
2. When I use the links the elements are activated but they do not
   answer to the anchor petition.
3. I also I would like, when I activate one of the elements of the
   menu, to change the image with another one. For example, change the
   first icon with this one:
   [image: this one]

Thank you in advance, this problem is driving me crazy!

Comment: Is your window actually in an overflow (y) state? Also, try $(window) instead of $(document)

Comment: I think you want `$('.topmenu a')` to be either `$('.header a')` or `$('a.topmenu')` in both places where it appears in your `onScroll` function. As it stands now, the selector is looking for anchors which are children of `.topmenu` elements - but the anchors in your code are the `.topmenu` elements not children of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may simplify your code:

use mousemove/mouseenter instead of scroll event.

The snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('a[href^="#"].topmenu').on('click', function (e) {
    $('a.topmenu').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});

$(document).on('mousemove mouseenter', 'div.cuerpo div', function(event) {
  $('a.topmenu').removeClass('active');
  $('a[href="#' + this.previousElementSibling.id + '"].topmenu').addClass('active');
});

$(document).on('keyup', function (e) {
  var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
  if ((charCode >= 49 && charCode <= 53) || (charCode >= 97 && charCode <= 101)) {
    $('a[href="#anchor' + String.fromCharCode(charCode) + '"].topmenu').trigger('click');
    $(document).scrollTop( $('#anchor' + String.fromCharCode(charCode)).offset().top);  
  }
});
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

div{
  overflow: auto;
}

/*Menu de cabecera*/

.header{
  margin:auto;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  width:100%;
  padding-top:7px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  z-index:5;
  border-bottom:solid 2px #5882FA;
}

.header a{
  text-decoration:none;
}

.topmenu img{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border-radius:90px;
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  margin:2px 5px 17px 5px;
}

.topmenu img:active{
  transform: translateY(4px);
}

.topmenu img:hover{
  box-shadow:0px 2px 1px #5882FA;
}


/*Tooltips*/

.topmenu span{
  visibility:hidden;
  width: 120px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 2px 0;
  margin:1px;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  text-decoration:none;

  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  opacity: 0;

  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: 2s;
}

.topmenu:hover span{
  visibility:visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.active{
  background-color:black;
}

.cuerpo{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top:90px;
}

.cuerpo div{
  height: 590px;
  margin: 5px 15%;
}

.anchor{
  display: block;
  height: 90px;
  margin-top: -90px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<nav class="header">

    <div>

        <a href="#anchor1" class="topmenu">
            <img src="http://es.seaicons.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Number-1-icon.png">
            <span id="profile">Menu 1</span>
        </a>

        <a href="#anchor2" class="topmenu">
            <img src="http://es.seaicons.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Number-2-icon.png">
            <span id="exp">Menu 2</span>
        </a>

        <a href="#anchor3" class="topmenu">
            <img src="http://es.seaicons.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Number-3-icon.png">
            <span id="hab">Menu 3</span>
        </a>

        <a href="#anchor4" class="topmenu">
            <img src="http://es.seaicons.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Number-4-icon.png">
            <span id="pro">Menu 4</span>
        </a>

        <a href="#anchor5" class="topmenu">
            <img src="http://es.seaicons.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Number-5-icon.png">
            <span id="contact">Menu 5</span>
        </a>

    </div>

</nav>

<div class="cuerpo">
    <span class="anchor" id="anchor1"></span>
    <div style="background-color:blue">Area 1</div>

    <span class="anchor" id="anchor2"></span>
    <div style="background-color:red">Area 2</div>

    <span class="anchor" id="anchor3"></span>
    <div style="background-color:yellow">Area 3</div>

    <span class="anchor" id="anchor4"></span>
    <div style="background-color:brown">Area 4</div>

    <span class="anchor" id="anchor5"></span>
    <div style="background-color:green">Area 5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! is working! But now i have another problem. When i use the keyarrows is not working, i tried using the events "keypress", "keyup", "keydown" but it just change when i finish pushing and not during the process of pushing. 

`$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  $('a[href="#' + this.previousElementSibling.id + '"].topmenu').addClass('active');
  $('a.topmenu').removeClass('active');
});`

Comment: There is also, another problem, if i move the mouse out of the div, the menu isnt reacting, what i really need is to implement this with the scrolling event as they show it in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/up4nu/, but i cant make it work.

Comment: @Javi Snippet updated. Now you can use the keyup event so with keyboard char 1,2,3,4,5 you can select directly the corresponding menu. For the other question: if you change the aspect of the fiddle it's clear that this solution needs to be adjusted. For this other problem you may take a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519043/get-mouse-position-on-scroll.  Now, is this question closed/accepted?