# Custom Circle Cursor With jQuery And CSS3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mouseevent, mouselistener

I'm trying to replicate the mouse pointer effect from [this page](https://nspc.co.jp/) but I cannot reach the same incredible fluidity.

I've developed a code (jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bazn92we/6/)) thanks to [this](https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Custom-Cursor-jQuery-CSS3.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519043/get-mouse-position-on-scroll) tutorials.

```js
//Ombra Cursore Mouse
var lastScrolledLeft = 0;
var lastScrolledTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  if (lastScrolledLeft != $(document).scrollLeft()) {
    lastScrolledLeft = $(document).scrollLeft();
  }
  if (lastScrolledTop != $(document).scrollTop()) {
    lastScrolledTop = $(document).scrollTop();
  }
});
$(document)
  .mousemove(function(e) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.cursor')
        .eq(0)
        .css({
          left: e.clientX + lastScrolledLeft,
          top: e.clientY + lastScrolledTop
        });
    }, 100);
  });
```

```css
.cursor {
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  background-color: #E74C3C;
  z-index: 10000;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cursor"></div>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus imperdiet erat a bibendum blandit. Nullam vitae mauris vel urna tempus hendrerit. Phasellus et odio est. Mauris a felis vel justo egestas dictum. Donec ultricies fermentum mattis. Pellentesque
  habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In ac nisl a libero scelerisque blandit. Nam neque tortor, bibendum eget augue et, accumsan faucibus quam. Aenean sed magna quis libero facilisis blandit ut at enim. Fusce
  faucibus porttitor arcu sit amet finibus. Maecenas fermentum nulla non erat cursus laoreet. Nullam erat arcu, volutpat ac ligula quis, tempus consectetur lorem. Aenean pellentesque felis a nisi viverra dictum. Curabitur at magna accumsan, scelerisque
  erat non, suscipit lorem. Aenean consectetur sem facilisis sem aliquet imperdiet. Aliquam mauris elit, finibus in tortor quis, cursus euismod urna. Integer vitae ultricies dui. Integer et nibh non nulla elementum finibus. Pellentesque ultricies dapibus
  dolor, consequat congue neque pharetra ac. Nam mollis risus nunc, ut accumsan diam semper quis. Aenean luctus magna ac tellus tempus auctor. Donec quis metus rhoncus, sollicitudin neque ac, maximus felis. Aliquam interdum mi ac sem gravida aliquet.
  Sed porttitor porttitor pharetra. Nunc diam sapien, consequat dapibus tincidunt in, pellentesque id est. Morbi in dui ac lorem interdum feugiat. Curabitur eget justo fermentum, mattis sapien in, malesuada dolor. Praesent in risus in metus iaculis volutpat.
  Nam venenatis, magna eu dignissim vehicula, elit felis faucibus odio, eget interdum lorem justo eu elit. Nunc imperdiet neque ut mollis ultricies. Vestibulum viverra vel magna a dignissim. Nunc sed enim at massa commodo egestas. Nam id odio cursus,
  imperdiet magna nec, accumsan est. Aliquam vulputate tempor urna interdum rutrum. Nulla facilisi. Integer sed convallis justo. Sed a vestibulum dolor. Morbi nec dui a lectus viverra ultricies quis ut risus. Quisque eget hendrerit tortor. Morbi lobortis
  sagittis sodales. Quisque ultricies, diam ut ornare tincidunt, ante tellus ornare neque, eget faucibus erat enim nec arcu. Nam nec lobortis turpis. Curabitur molestie euismod tellus ac molestie. Proin malesuada suscipit suscipit. Nulla imperdiet mauris
  ullamcorper, scelerisque nibh lacinia, hendrerit justo. Curabitur venenatis odio lorem, ac bibendum sem rutrum eget. Sed nec finibus nisi, eu eleifend lacus. Vestibulum varius pulvinar ultrices. Suspendisse egestas nunc vel fringilla efficitur. Cras
  id eleifend arcu. Curabitur pellentesque scelerisque mi, sit amet ultrices tortor imperdiet a. Vestibulum ut dolor non est viverra rhoncus. Morbi ultrices dolor at erat pharetra, dignissim porta magna ultrices. Praesent sapien dui, sagittis eget tellus
  quis, tincidunt sollicitudin erat. Morbi commodo, dolor id mollis varius, lacus quam tincidunt odio, ut sagittis nisi massa sed quam. In eget est eget elit sollicitudin sollicitudin. Sed non nisl sed ipsum eleifend interdum ac quis enim. Nulla malesuada
  molestie sapien et fermentum. Nullam eu dui pretium, malesuada quam ut, hendrerit ipsum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus imperdiet erat a bibendum blandit. Nullam vitae mauris vel urna tempus hendrerit. Phasellus et
  odio est. Mauris a felis vel justo egestas dictum. Donec ultricies fermentum mattis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In ac nisl a libero scelerisque blandit. Nam neque tortor, bibendum eget
  augue et, accumsan faucibus quam. Aenean sed magna quis libero facilisis blandit ut at enim. Fusce faucibus porttitor arcu sit amet finibus. Maecenas fermentum nulla non erat cursus laoreet. Nullam erat arcu, volutpat ac ligula quis, tempus consectetur
  lorem. Aenean pellentesque felis a nisi viverra dictum. Curabitur at magna accumsan, scelerisque erat non, suscipit lorem. Aenean consectetur sem facilisis sem aliquet imperdiet. Aliquam mauris elit, finibus in tortor quis, cursus euismod urna. Integer
  vitae ultricies dui. Integer et nibh non nulla elementum finibus. Pellentesque ultricies dapibus dolor, consequat congue neque pharetra ac. Nam mollis risus nunc, ut accumsan diam semper quis. Aenean luctus magna ac tellus tempus auctor. Donec quis
  metus rhoncus, sollicitudin neque ac, maximus felis. Aliquam interdum mi ac sem gravida aliquet. Sed porttitor porttitor pharetra. Nunc diam sapien, consequat dapibus tincidunt in, pellentesque id est. Morbi in dui ac lorem interdum feugiat. Curabitur
  eget justo fermentum, mattis sapien in, malesuada dolor. Praesent in risus in metus iaculis volutpat. Nam venenatis, magna eu dignissim vehicula, elit felis faucibus odio, eget interdum lorem justo eu elit. Nunc imperdiet neque ut mollis ultricies.
  Vestibulum viverra vel magna a dignissim. Nunc sed enim at massa commodo egestas. Nam id odio cursus, imperdiet magna nec, accumsan est. Aliquam vulputate tempor urna interdum rutrum. Nulla facilisi. Integer sed convallis justo. Sed a vestibulum dolor.
  Morbi nec dui a lectus viverra ultricies quis ut risus. Quisque eget hendrerit tortor. Morbi lobortis sagittis sodales. Quisque ultricies, diam ut ornare tincidunt, ante tellus ornare neque, eget faucibus erat enim nec arcu. Nam nec lobortis turpis.
  Curabitur molestie euismod tellus ac molestie. Proin malesuada suscipit suscipit. Nulla imperdiet mauris ullamcorper, scelerisque nibh lacinia, hendrerit justo. Curabitur venenatis odio lorem, ac bibendum sem rutrum eget. Sed nec finibus nisi, eu eleifend
  lacus. Vestibulum varius pulvinar ultrices. Suspendisse egestas nunc vel fringilla efficitur. Cras id eleifend arcu. Curabitur pellentesque scelerisque mi, sit amet ultrices tortor imperdiet a. Vestibulum ut dolor non est viverra rhoncus. Morbi ultrices
  dolor at erat pharetra, dignissim porta magna ultrices. Praesent sapien dui, sagittis eget tellus quis, tincidunt sollicitudin erat. Morbi commodo, dolor id mollis varius, lacus quam tincidunt odio, ut sagittis nisi massa sed quam. In eget est eget
  elit sollicitudin sollicitudin. Sed non nisl sed ipsum eleifend interdum ac quis enim. Nulla malesuada molestie sapien et fermentum. Nullam eu dui pretium, malesuada quam ut, hendrerit ipsum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  Vivamus imperdiet erat a bibendum blandit. Nullam vitae mauris vel urna tempus hendrerit. Phasellus et odio est. Mauris a felis vel justo egestas dictum. Donec ultricies fermentum mattis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
  fames ac turpis egestas. In ac nisl a libero scelerisque blandit. Nam neque tortor, bibendum eget augue et, accumsan faucibus quam. Aenean sed magna quis libero facilisis blandit ut at enim. Fusce faucibus porttitor arcu sit amet finibus. Maecenas fermentum
  nulla non erat cursus laoreet. Nullam erat arcu, volutpat ac ligula quis, tempus consectetur lorem. Aenean pellentesque felis a nisi viverra dictum. Curabitur at magna accumsan, scelerisque erat non, suscipit lorem. Aenean consectetur sem facilisis
  sem aliquet imperdiet. Aliquam mauris elit, finibus in tortor quis, cursus euismod urna. Integer vitae ultricies dui. Integer et nibh non nulla elementum finibus. Pellentesque ultricies dapibus dolor, consequat congue neque pharetra ac. Nam mollis risus
  nunc, ut accumsan diam semper quis. Aenean luctus magna ac tellus tempus auctor. Donec quis metus rhoncus, sollicitudin neque ac, maximus felis. Aliquam interdum mi ac sem gravida aliquet. Sed porttitor porttitor pharetra. Nunc diam sapien, consequat
  dapibus tincidunt in, pellentesque id est. Morbi in dui ac lorem interdum feugiat. Curabitur eget justo fermentum, mattis sapien in, malesuada dolor. Praesent in risus in metus iaculis volutpat. Nam venenatis, magna eu dignissim vehicula, elit felis
  faucibus odio, eget interdum lorem justo eu elit. Nunc imperdiet neque ut mollis ultricies. Vestibulum viverra vel magna a dignissim. Nunc sed enim at massa commodo egestas. Nam id odio cursus, imperdiet magna nec, accumsan est. Aliquam vulputate tempor
  urna interdum rutrum. Nulla facilisi. Integer sed convallis justo. Sed a vestibulum dolor. Morbi nec dui a lectus viverra ultricies quis ut risus. Quisque eget hendrerit tortor. Morbi lobortis sagittis sodales. Quisque ultricies, diam ut ornare tincidunt,
  ante tellus ornare neque, eget faucibus erat enim nec arcu. Nam nec lobortis turpis. Curabitur molestie euismod tellus ac molestie. Proin malesuada suscipit suscipit. Nulla imperdiet mauris ullamcorper, scelerisque nibh lacinia, hendrerit justo. Curabitur
  venenatis odio lorem, ac bibendum sem rutrum eget. Sed nec finibus nisi, eu eleifend lacus. Vestibulum varius pulvinar ultrices. Suspendisse egestas nunc vel fringilla efficitur. Cras id eleifend arcu. Curabitur pellentesque scelerisque mi, sit amet
  ultrices tortor imperdiet a. Vestibulum ut dolor non est viverra rhoncus. Morbi ultrices dolor at erat pharetra, dignissim porta magna ultrices. Praesent sapien dui, sagittis eget tellus quis, tincidunt sollicitudin erat. Morbi commodo, dolor id mollis
  varius, lacus quam tincidunt odio, ut sagittis nisi massa sed quam. In eget est eget elit sollicitudin sollicitudin. Sed non nisl sed ipsum eleifend interdum ac quis enim. Nulla malesuada molestie sapien et fermentum. Nullam eu dui pretium, malesuada
  quam ut, hendrerit ipsum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus imperdiet erat a bibendum blandit. Nullam vitae mauris vel urna tempus hendrerit. Phasellus et odio est. Mauris a felis vel justo egestas dictum. Donec ultricies
  fermentum mattis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In ac nisl a libero scelerisque blandit. Nam neque tortor, bibendum eget augue et, accumsan faucibus quam. Aenean sed magna quis libero facilisis
  blandit ut at enim. Fusce faucibus porttitor arcu sit amet finibus. Maecenas fermentum nulla non erat cursus laoreet. Nullam erat arcu, volutpat ac ligula quis, tempus consectetur lorem. Aenean pellentesque felis a nisi viverra dictum. Curabitur at
  magna accumsan, scelerisque erat non, suscipit lorem. Aenean consectetur sem facilisis sem aliquet imperdiet. Aliquam mauris elit, finibus in tortor quis, cursus euismod urna. Integer vitae ultricies dui. Integer et nibh non nulla elementum finibus.
  Pellentesque ultricies dapibus dolor, consequat congue neque pharetra ac. Nam mollis risus nunc, ut accumsan diam semper quis. Aenean luctus magna ac tellus tempus auctor. Donec quis metus rhoncus, sollicitudin neque ac, maximus felis. Aliquam interdum
  mi ac sem gravida aliquet. Sed porttitor porttitor pharetra. Nunc diam sapien, consequat dapibus tincidunt in, pellentesque id est. Morbi in dui ac lorem interdum feugiat. Curabitur eget justo fermentum, mattis sapien in, malesuada dolor. Praesent in
  risus in metus iaculis volutpat. Nam venenatis, magna eu dignissim vehicula, elit felis faucibus odio, eget interdum lorem justo eu elit. Nunc imperdiet neque ut mollis ultricies. Vestibulum viverra vel magna a dignissim. Nunc sed enim at massa commodo
  egestas. Nam id odio cursus, imperdiet magna nec, accumsan est. Aliquam vulputate tempor urna interdum rutrum. Nulla facilisi. Integer sed convallis justo. Sed a vestibulum dolor. Morbi nec dui a lectus viverra ultricies quis ut risus. Quisque eget
  hendrerit tortor. Morbi lobortis sagittis sodales. Quisque ultricies, diam ut ornare tincidunt, ante tellus ornare neque, eget faucibus erat enim nec arcu. Nam nec lobortis turpis. Curabitur molestie euismod tellus ac molestie. Proin malesuada suscipit
  suscipit. Nulla imperdiet mauris ullamcorper, scelerisque nibh lacinia, hendrerit justo. Curabitur venenatis odio lorem, ac bibendum sem rutrum eget. Sed nec finibus nisi, eu eleifend lacus. Vestibulum varius pulvinar ultrices. Suspendisse egestas nunc
  vel fringilla efficitur. Cras id eleifend arcu. Curabitur pellentesque scelerisque mi, sit amet ultrices tortor imperdiet a. Vestibulum ut dolor non est viverra rhoncus. Morbi ultrices dolor at erat pharetra, dignissim porta magna ultrices. Praesent
  sapien dui, sagittis eget tellus quis, tincidunt sollicitudin erat. Morbi commodo, dolor id mollis varius, lacus quam tincidunt odio, ut sagittis nisi massa sed quam. In eget est eget elit sollicitudin sollicitudin. Sed non nisl sed ipsum eleifend interdum
  ac quis enim. Nulla malesuada molestie sapien et fermentum. Nullam eu dui pretium, malesuada quam ut, hendrerit ipsum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus imperdiet erat a bibendum blandit. Nullam vitae mauris vel urna tempus
  hendrerit. Phasellus et odio est. Mauris a felis vel justo egestas dictum. Donec ultricies fermentum mattis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In ac nisl a libero scelerisque blandit. Nam neque
  tortor, bibendum eget augue et, accumsan faucibus quam. Aenean sed magna quis libero facilisis blandit ut at enim. Fusce faucibus porttitor arcu sit amet finibus. Maecenas fermentum nulla non erat cursus laoreet. Nullam erat arcu, volutpat ac ligula
  quis, tempus consectetur lorem. Aenean pellentesque felis a nisi viverra dictum. Curabitur at magna accumsan, scelerisque erat non, suscipit lorem. Aenean consectetur sem facilisis sem aliquet imperdiet. Aliquam mauris elit, finibus in tortor quis,
  cursus euismod urna. Integer vitae ultricies dui. Integer et nibh non nulla elementum finibus. Pellentesque ultricies dapibus dolor, consequat congue neque pharetra ac. Nam mollis risus nunc, ut accumsan diam semper quis. Aenean luctus magna ac tellus
  tempus auctor. Donec quis metus rhoncus, sollicitudin neque ac, maximus felis. Aliquam interdum mi ac sem gravida aliquet. Sed porttitor porttitor pharetra. Nunc diam sapien, consequat dapibus tincidunt in, pellentesque id est. Morbi in dui ac lorem
  interdum feugiat. Curabitur eget justo fermentum, mattis sapien in, malesuada dolor. Praesent in risus in metus iaculis volutpat. Nam venenatis, magna eu dignissim vehicula, elit felis faucibus odio, eget interdum lorem justo eu elit. Nunc imperdiet
  neque ut mollis ultricies. Vestibulum viverra vel magna a dignissim. Nunc sed enim at massa commodo egestas. Nam id odio cursus, imperdiet magna nec, accumsan est. Aliquam vulputate tempor urna interdum rutrum. Nulla facilisi. Integer sed convallis
  justo. Sed a vestibulum dolor. Morbi nec dui a lectus viverra ultricies quis ut risus. Quisque eget hendrerit tortor. Morbi lobortis sagittis sodales. Quisque ultricies, diam ut ornare tincidunt, ante tellus ornare neque, eget faucibus erat enim nec
  arcu. Nam nec lobortis turpis. Curabitur molestie euismod tellus ac molestie. Proin malesuada suscipit suscipit. Nulla imperdiet mauris ullamcorper, scelerisque nibh lacinia, hendrerit justo. Curabitur venenatis odio lorem, ac bibendum sem rutrum eget.
  Sed nec finibus nisi, eu eleifend lacus. Vestibulum varius pulvinar ultrices. Suspendisse egestas nunc vel fringilla efficitur. Cras id eleifend arcu. Curabitur pellentesque scelerisque mi, sit amet ultrices tortor imperdiet a. Vestibulum ut dolor non
  est viverra rhoncus. Morbi ultrices dolor at erat pharetra, dignissim porta magna ultrices. Praesent sapien dui, sagittis eget tellus quis, tincidunt sollicitudin erat. Morbi commodo, dolor id mollis varius, lacus quam tincidunt odio, ut sagittis nisi
  massa sed quam. In eget est eget elit sollicitudin sollicitudin. Sed non nisl sed ipsum eleifend interdum ac quis enim. Nulla malesuada molestie sapien et fermentum. Nullam eu dui pretium, malesuada quam ut, hendrerit ipsum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus imperdiet erat a bibendum blandit. Nullam vitae mauris vel urna tempus hendrerit. Phasellus et odio est. Mauris a felis vel justo egestas dictum. Donec ultricies fermentum mattis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
  senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In ac nisl a libero scelerisque blandit. Nam neque tortor, bibendum eget augue et, accumsan faucibus quam. Aenean sed magna quis libero facilisis blandit ut at enim. Fusce faucibus porttitor arcu
  sit amet finibus. Maecenas fermentum nulla non erat cursus laoreet. Nullam erat arcu, volutpat ac ligula quis, tempus consectetur lorem. Aenean pellentesque felis a nisi viverra dictum. Curabitur at magna accumsan, scelerisque erat non, suscipit lorem.
  Aenean consectetur sem facilisis sem aliquet imperdiet. Aliquam mauris elit, finibus in tortor quis, cursus euismod urna. Integer vitae ultricies dui. Integer et nibh non nulla elementum finibus. Pellentesque ultricies dapibus dolor, consequat congue
  neque pharetra ac. Nam mollis risus nunc, ut accumsan diam semper quis. Aenean luctus magna ac tellus tempus auctor. Donec quis metus rhoncus, sollicitudin neque ac, maximus felis. Aliquam interdum mi ac sem gravida aliquet. Sed porttitor porttitor
  pharetra. Nunc diam sapien, consequat dapibus tincidunt in, pellentesque id est. Morbi in dui ac lorem interdum feugiat. Curabitur eget justo fermentum, mattis sapien in, malesuada dolor. Praesent in risus in metus iaculis volutpat. Nam venenatis, magna
  eu dignissim vehicula, elit felis faucibus odio, eget interdum lorem justo eu elit. Nunc imperdiet neque ut mollis ultricies. Vestibulum viverra vel magna a dignissim. Nunc sed enim at massa commodo egestas. Nam id odio cursus, imperdiet magna nec,
  accumsan est. Aliquam vulputate tempor urna interdum rutrum. Nulla facilisi. Integer sed convallis justo. Sed a vestibulum dolor. Morbi nec dui a lectus viverra ultricies quis ut risus. Quisque eget hendrerit tortor. Morbi lobortis sagittis sodales.
  Quisque ultricies, diam ut ornare tincidunt, ante tellus ornare neque, eget faucibus erat enim nec arcu. Nam nec lobortis turpis. Curabitur molestie euismod tellus ac molestie. Proin malesuada suscipit suscipit. Nulla imperdiet mauris ullamcorper, scelerisque
  nibh lacinia, hendrerit justo. Curabitur venenatis odio lorem, ac bibendum sem rutrum eget. Sed nec finibus nisi, eu eleifend lacus. Vestibulum varius pulvinar ultrices. Suspendisse egestas nunc vel fringilla efficitur. Cras id eleifend arcu. Curabitur
  pellentesque scelerisque mi, sit amet ultrices tortor imperdiet a. Vestibulum ut dolor non est viverra rhoncus. Morbi ultrices dolor at erat pharetra, dignissim porta magna ultrices. Praesent sapien dui, sagittis eget tellus quis, tincidunt sollicitudin
  erat. Morbi commodo, dolor id mollis varius, lacus quam tincidunt odio, ut sagittis nisi massa sed quam. In eget est eget elit sollicitudin sollicitudin. Sed non nisl sed ipsum eleifend interdum ac quis enim. Nulla malesuada molestie sapien et fermentum.
  Nullam eu dui pretium, malesuada quam ut, hendrerit ipsum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus imperdiet erat a bibendum blandit. Nullam vitae mauris vel urna tempus hendrerit. Phasellus et odio est. Mauris a felis vel justo
  egestas dictum. Donec ultricies fermentum mattis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In ac nisl a libero scelerisque blandit. Nam neque tortor, bibendum eget augue et, accumsan faucibus quam.
  Aenean sed magna quis libero facilisis blandit ut at enim. Fusce faucibus porttitor arcu sit amet finibus. Maecenas fermentum nulla non erat cursus laoreet. Nullam erat arcu, volutpat ac ligula quis, tempus consectetur lorem. Aenean pellentesque felis
  a nisi viverra dictum. Curabitur at magna accumsan, scelerisque erat non, suscipit lorem. Aenean consectetur sem facilisis sem aliquet imperdiet. Aliquam mauris elit, finibus in tortor quis, cursus euismod urna. Integer vitae ultricies dui. Integer
  et nibh non nulla elementum finibus. Pellentesque ultricies dapibus dolor, consequat congue neque pharetra ac. Nam mollis risus nunc, ut accumsan diam semper quis. Aenean luctus magna ac tellus tempus auctor. Donec quis metus rhoncus, sollicitudin neque
  ac, maximus felis. Aliquam interdum mi ac sem gravida aliquet. Sed porttitor porttitor pharetra. Nunc diam sapien, consequat dapibus tincidunt in, pellentesque id est. Morbi in dui ac lorem interdum feugiat. Curabitur eget justo fermentum, mattis sapien
  in, malesuada dolor. Praesent in risus in metus iaculis volutpat. Nam venenatis, magna eu dignissim vehicula, elit felis faucibus odio, eget interdum lorem justo eu elit. Nunc imperdiet neque ut mollis ultricies. Vestibulum viverra vel magna a dignissim.
  Nunc sed enim at massa commodo egestas. Nam id odio cursus, imperdiet magna nec, accumsan est. Aliquam vulputate tempor urna interdum rutrum. Nulla facilisi. Integer sed convallis justo. Sed a vestibulum dolor. Morbi nec dui a lectus viverra ultricies
  quis ut risus. Quisque eget hendrerit tortor. Morbi lobortis sagittis sodales. Quisque ultricies, diam ut ornare tincidunt, ante tellus ornare neque, eget faucibus erat enim nec arcu. Nam nec lobortis turpis. Curabitur molestie euismod tellus ac molestie.
  Proin malesuada suscipit suscipit. Nulla imperdiet mauris ullamcorper, scelerisque nibh lacinia, hendrerit justo. Curabitur venenatis odio lorem, ac bibendum sem rutrum eget. Sed nec finibus nisi, eu eleifend lacus. Vestibulum varius pulvinar ultrices.
  Suspendisse egestas nunc vel fringilla efficitur. Cras id eleifend arcu. Curabitur pellentesque scelerisque mi, sit amet ultrices tortor imperdiet a. Vestibulum ut dolor non est viverra rhoncus. Morbi ultrices dolor at erat pharetra, dignissim porta
  magna ultrices. Praesent sapien dui, sagittis eget tellus quis, tincidunt sollicitudin erat. Morbi commodo, dolor id mollis varius, lacus quam tincidunt odio, ut sagittis nisi massa sed quam. In eget est eget elit sollicitudin sollicitudin. Sed non
  nisl sed ipsum eleifend interdum ac quis enim. Nulla malesuada molestie sapien et fermentum. Nullam eu dui pretium, malesuada quam ut, hendrerit ipsum.

</p>
```

With only the first tutorial, there is a scroll issue because, when i scroll the page, the e.clientX/Y not recognise the new mouse position.

As next step, I've used e.pageX/Y and it works but it is not fluid, so I've used the second tutorial to get more fluidity by replacing the e.pageX/Y with the coordinates get on gap scrolling.

Any suggest to increase the fluidity and let the cursor not stucks in his position when scrolling?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't make the cursor `position: fixed;` and listen to the mousemove from `body`?

```js
//Ombra Cursore Mouse
var lastScrolledLeft = 0;
var lastScrolledTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  if (lastScrolledLeft != $(document).scrollLeft()) {
    lastScrolledLeft = $(document).scrollLeft();
  }
  if (lastScrolledTop != $(document).scrollTop()) {
    lastScrolledTop = $(document).scrollTop();
  }
});
$('body')
  .mousemove(function(e) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.cursor')
        .eq(0)
        .css({
          left: e.clientX ,
          top: e.clientY 
        });
    }, 100);
  });
```

```css
.cursor {
  position: fixed;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  background-color: #E74C3C;
  z-index: 10000;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cursor"></div>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus imperdiet erat a bibendum blandit. Nullam vitae mauris vel urna tempus hendrerit. Phasellus et odio est. Mauris a felis vel justo egestas dictum. Donec ultricies fermentum mattis. Pellentesque
  habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In ac nisl a libero scelerisque blandit. Nam neque tortor, bibendum eget augue et, accumsan faucibus quam. Aenean sed magna quis libero facilisis blandit ut at enim. Fusce
  faucibus porttitor arcu sit amet finibus. Maecenas fermentum nulla non erat cursus laoreet. Nullam erat arcu, volutpat ac ligula quis, tempus consectetur lorem. Aenean pellentesque felis a nisi viverra dictum. Curabitur at magna accumsan, scelerisque
  erat non, suscipit lorem. Aenean consectetur sem facilisis sem aliquet imperdiet. Aliquam mauris elit, finibus in tortor quis, cursus euismod urna. Integer vitae ultricies dui. Integer et nibh non nulla elementum finibus. Pellentesque ultricies dapibus
  dolor, consequat congue neque pharetra ac. Nam mollis risus nunc, ut accumsan diam semper quis. Aenean luctus magna ac tellus tempus auctor. Donec quis metus rhoncus, sollicitudin neque ac, maximus felis. Aliquam interdum mi ac sem gravida aliquet.
  Sed porttitor porttitor pharetra. Nunc diam sapien, consequat dapibus tincidunt in, pellentesque id est. Morbi in dui ac lorem interdum feugiat. Curabitur eget justo fermentum, mattis sapien in, malesuada dolor. Praesent in risus in metus iaculis volutpat.
  Nam venenatis, magna eu dignissim vehicula, elit felis faucibus odio, eget interdum lorem justo eu elit. Nunc imperdiet neque ut mollis ultricies. Vestibulum viverra vel magna a dignissim. Nunc sed enim at massa commodo egestas. Nam id odio cursus,
  imperdiet magna nec, accumsan est. Aliquam vulputate tempor urna interdum rutrum. Nulla facilisi. Integer sed convallis justo. Sed a vestibulum dolor. Morbi nec dui a lectus viverra ultricies quis ut risus. Quisque eget hendrerit tortor. Morbi lobortis
  sagittis sodales. Quisque ultricies, diam ut ornare tincidunt, ante tellus ornare neque, eget faucibus erat enim nec arcu. Nam nec lobortis turpis. Curabitur molestie euismod tellus ac molestie. Proin malesuada suscipit suscipit. Nulla imperdiet mauris
  ullamcorper, scelerisque nibh lacinia, hendrerit justo. Curabitur venenatis odio lorem, ac bibendum sem rutrum eget. Sed nec finibus nisi, eu eleifend lacus. Vestibulum varius pulvinar ultrices. Suspendisse egestas nunc vel fringilla efficitur. Cras
  id eleifend arcu. Curabitur pellentesque scelerisque mi, sit amet ultrices tortor imperdiet a. Vestibulum ut dolor non est viverra rhoncus. Morbi ultrices dolor at erat pharetra, dignissim porta magna ultrices. Praesent sapien dui, sagittis eget tellus
  quis, tincidunt sollicitudin erat. Morbi commodo, dolor id mollis varius, lacus quam tincidunt odio, ut sagittis nisi massa sed quam. In eget est eget elit sollicitudin sollicitudin. Sed non nisl sed ipsum eleifend interdum ac quis enim. Nulla malesuada
  molestie sapien et fermentum. Nullam eu dui pretium, malesuada quam ut, hendrerit ipsum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus imperdiet erat a bibendum blandit. Nullam vitae mauris vel urna tempus hendrerit. Phasellus et
  odio est. Mauris a felis vel justo egestas dictum. Donec ultricies fermentum mattis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In ac nisl a libero scelerisque blandit. Nam neque tortor, bibendum eget
  augue et, accumsan faucibus quam. Aenean sed magna quis libero facilisis blandit ut at enim. Fusce faucibus porttitor arcu sit amet finibus. Maecenas fermentum nulla non erat cursus laoreet. Nullam erat arcu, volutpat ac ligula quis, tempus consectetur
  lorem. Aenean pellentesque felis a nisi viverra dictum. Curabitur at magna accumsan, scelerisque erat non, suscipit lorem. Aenean consectetur sem facilisis sem aliquet imperdiet. Aliquam mauris elit, finibus in tortor quis, cursus euismod urna. Integer
  vitae ultricies dui. Integer et nibh non nulla elementum finibus. Pellentesque ultricies dapibus dolor, consequat congue neque pharetra ac. Nam mollis risus nunc, ut accumsan diam semper quis. Aenean luctus magna ac tellus tempus auctor. Donec quis
  metus rhoncus, sollicitudin neque ac, maximus felis. Aliquam interdum mi ac sem gravida aliquet. Sed porttitor porttitor pharetra. Nunc diam sapien, consequat dapibus tincidunt in, pellentesque id est. Morbi in dui ac lorem interdum feugiat. Curabitur
  eget justo fermentum, mattis sapien in, malesuada dolor. Praesent in risus in metus iaculis volutpat. Nam venenatis, magna eu dignissim vehicula, elit felis faucibus odio, eget interdum lorem justo eu elit. Nunc imperdiet neque ut mollis ultricies.
  Vestibulum viverra vel magna a dignissim. Nunc sed enim at massa commodo egestas. Nam id odio cursus, imperdiet magna nec, accumsan est. Aliquam vulputate tempor urna interdum rutrum. Nulla facilisi. Integer sed convallis justo. Sed a vestibulum dolor.
  Morbi nec dui a lectus viverra ultricies quis ut risus. Quisque eget hendrerit tortor. Morbi lobortis sagittis sodales. Quisque ultricies, diam ut ornare tincidunt, ante tellus ornare neque, eget faucibus erat enim nec arcu. Nam nec lobortis turpis.
  Curabitur molestie euismod tellus ac molestie. Proin malesuada suscipit suscipit. Nulla imperdiet mauris ullamcorper, scelerisque nibh lacinia, hendrerit justo. Curabitur venenatis odio lorem, ac bibendum sem rutrum eget. Sed nec finibus nisi, eu eleifend
  lacus. Vestibulum varius pulvinar ultrices. Suspendisse egestas nunc vel fringilla efficitur. Cras id eleifend arcu. Curabitur pellentesque scelerisque mi, sit amet ultrices tortor imperdiet a. Vestibulum ut dolor non est viverra rhoncus. Morbi ultrices
  dolor at erat pharetra, dignissim porta magna ultrices. Praesent sapien dui, sagittis eget tellus quis, tincidunt sollicitudin erat. Morbi commodo, dolor id mollis varius, lacus quam tincidunt odio, ut sagittis nisi massa sed quam. In eget est eget
  elit sollicitudin sollicitudin. Sed non nisl sed ipsum eleifend interdum ac quis enim. Nulla malesuada molestie sapien et fermentum. Nullam eu dui pretium, malesuada quam ut, hendrerit ipsum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  Vivamus imperdiet erat a bibendum blandit. Nullam vitae mauris vel urna tempus hendrerit. Phasellus et odio est. Mauris a felis vel justo egestas dictum. Donec ultricies fermentum mattis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
  fames ac turpis egestas. In ac nisl a libero scelerisque blandit. Nam neque tortor, bibendum eget augue et, accumsan faucibus quam. Aenean sed magna quis libero facilisis blandit ut at enim. Fusce faucibus porttitor arcu sit amet finibus. Maecenas fermentum
  nulla non erat cursus laoreet. Nullam erat arcu, volutpat ac ligula quis, tempus consectetur lorem. Aenean pellentesque felis a nisi viverra dictum. Curabitur at magna accumsan, scelerisque erat non, suscipit lorem. Aenean consectetur sem facilisis
  sem aliquet imperdiet. Aliquam mauris elit, finibus in tortor quis, cursus euismod urna. Integer vitae ultricies dui. Integer et nibh non nulla elementum finibus. Pellentesque ultricies dapibus dolor, consequat congue neque pharetra ac. Nam mollis risus
  nunc, ut accumsan diam semper quis. Aenean luctus magna ac tellus tempus auctor. Donec quis metus rhoncus, sollicitudin neque ac, maximus felis. Aliquam interdum mi ac sem gravida aliquet. Sed porttitor porttitor pharetra. Nunc diam sapien, consequat
  dapibus tincidunt in, pellentesque id est. Morbi in dui ac lorem interdum feugiat. Curabitur eget justo fermentum, mattis sapien in, malesuada dolor. Praesent in risus in metus iaculis volutpat. Nam venenatis, magna eu dignissim vehicula, elit felis
  faucibus odio, eget interdum lorem justo eu elit. Nunc imperdiet neque ut mollis ultricies. Vestibulum viverra vel magna a dignissim. Nunc sed enim at massa commodo egestas. Nam id odio cursus, imperdiet magna nec, accumsan est. Aliquam vulputate tempor
  urna interdum rutrum. Nulla facilisi. Integer sed convallis justo. Sed a vestibulum dolor. Morbi nec dui a lectus viverra ultricies quis ut risus. Quisque eget hendrerit tortor. Morbi lobortis sagittis sodales. Quisque ultricies, diam ut ornare tincidunt,
  ante tellus ornare neque, eget faucibus erat enim nec arcu. Nam nec lobortis turpis. Curabitur molestie euismod tellus ac molestie. Proin malesuada suscipit suscipit. Nulla imperdiet mauris ullamcorper, scelerisque nibh lacinia, hendrerit justo. Curabitur
  venenatis odio lorem, ac bibendum sem rutrum eget. Sed nec finibus nisi, eu eleifend lacus. Vestibulum varius pulvinar ultrices. Suspendisse egestas nunc vel fringilla efficitur. Cras id eleifend arcu. Curabitur pellentesque scelerisque mi, sit amet
  ultrices tortor imperdiet a. Vestibulum ut dolor non est viverra rhoncus. Morbi ultrices dolor at erat pharetra, dignissim porta magna ultrices. Praesent sapien dui, sagittis eget tellus quis, tincidunt sollicitudin erat. Morbi commodo, dolor id mollis
  varius, lacus quam tincidunt odio, ut sagittis nisi massa sed quam. In eget est eget elit sollicitudin sollicitudin. Sed non nisl sed ipsum eleifend interdum ac quis enim. Nulla malesuada molestie sapien et fermentum. Nullam eu dui pretium, malesuada
  quam ut, hendrerit ipsum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus imperdiet erat a bibendum blandit. Nullam vitae mauris vel urna tempus hendrerit. Phasellus et odio est. Mauris a felis vel justo egestas dictum. Donec ultricies
  fermentum mattis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In ac nisl a libero scelerisque blandit. Nam neque tortor, bibendum eget augue et, accumsan faucibus quam. Aenean sed magna quis libero facilisis
  blandit ut at enim. Fusce faucibus porttitor arcu sit amet finibus. Maecenas fermentum nulla non erat cursus laoreet. Nullam erat arcu, volutpat ac ligula quis, tempus consectetur lorem. Aenean pellentesque felis a nisi viverra dictum. Curabitur at
  magna accumsan, scelerisque erat non, suscipit lorem. Aenean consectetur sem facilisis sem aliquet imperdiet. Aliquam mauris elit, finibus in tortor quis, cursus euismod urna. Integer vitae ultricies dui. Integer et nibh non nulla elementum finibus.
  Pellentesque ultricies dapibus dolor, consequat congue neque pharetra ac. Nam mollis risus nunc, ut accumsan diam semper quis. Aenean luctus magna ac tellus tempus auctor. Donec quis metus rhoncus, sollicitudin neque ac, maximus felis. Aliquam interdum
  mi ac sem gravida aliquet. Sed porttitor porttitor pharetra. Nunc diam sapien, consequat dapibus tincidunt in, pellentesque id est. Morbi in dui ac lorem interdum feugiat. Curabitur eget justo fermentum, mattis sapien in, malesuada dolor. Praesent in
  risus in metus iaculis volutpat. Nam venenatis, magna eu dignissim vehicula, elit felis faucibus odio, eget interdum lorem justo eu elit. Nunc imperdiet neque ut mollis ultricies. Vestibulum viverra vel magna a dignissim. Nunc sed enim at massa commodo
  egestas. Nam id odio cursus, imperdiet magna nec, accumsan est. Aliquam vulputate tempor urna interdum rutrum. Nulla facilisi. Integer sed convallis justo. Sed a vestibulum dolor. Morbi nec dui a lectus viverra ultricies quis ut risus. Quisque eget
  hendrerit tortor. Morbi lobortis sagittis sodales. Quisque ultricies, diam ut ornare tincidunt, ante tellus ornare neque, eget faucibus erat enim nec arcu. Nam nec lobortis turpis. Curabitur molestie euismod tellus ac molestie. Proin malesuada suscipit
  suscipit. Nulla imperdiet mauris ullamcorper, scelerisque nibh lacinia, hendrerit justo. Curabitur venenatis odio lorem, ac bibendum sem rutrum eget. Sed nec finibus nisi, eu eleifend lacus. Vestibulum varius pulvinar ultrices. Suspendisse egestas nunc
  vel fringilla efficitur. Cras id eleifend arcu. Curabitur pellentesque scelerisque mi, sit amet ultrices tortor imperdiet a. Vestibulum ut dolor non est viverra rhoncus. Morbi ultrices dolor at erat pharetra, dignissim porta magna ultrices. Praesent
  sapien dui, sagittis eget tellus quis, tincidunt sollicitudin erat. Morbi commodo, dolor id mollis varius, lacus quam tincidunt odio, ut sagittis nisi massa sed quam. In eget est eget elit sollicitudin sollicitudin. Sed non nisl sed ipsum eleifend interdum
  ac quis enim. Nulla malesuada molestie sapien et fermentum. Nullam eu dui pretium, malesuada quam ut, hendrerit ipsum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus imperdiet erat a bibendum blandit. Nullam vitae mauris vel urna tempus
  hendrerit. Phasellus et odio est. Mauris a felis vel justo egestas dictum. Donec ultricies fermentum mattis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In ac nisl a libero scelerisque blandit. Nam neque
  tortor, bibendum eget augue et, accumsan faucibus quam. Aenean sed magna quis libero facilisis blandit ut at enim. Fusce faucibus porttitor arcu sit amet finibus. Maecenas fermentum nulla non erat cursus laoreet. Nullam erat arcu, volutpat ac ligula
  quis, tempus consectetur lorem. Aenean pellentesque felis a nisi viverra dictum. Curabitur at magna accumsan, scelerisque erat non, suscipit lorem. Aenean consectetur sem facilisis sem aliquet imperdiet. Aliquam mauris elit, finibus in tortor quis,
  cursus euismod urna. Integer vitae ultricies dui. Integer et nibh non nulla elementum finibus. Pellentesque ultricies dapibus dolor, consequat congue neque pharetra ac. Nam mollis risus nunc, ut accumsan diam semper quis. Aenean luctus magna ac tellus
  tempus auctor. Donec quis metus rhoncus, sollicitudin neque ac, maximus felis. Aliquam interdum mi ac sem gravida aliquet. Sed porttitor porttitor pharetra. Nunc diam sapien, consequat dapibus tincidunt in, pellentesque id est. Morbi in dui ac lorem
  interdum feugiat. Curabitur eget justo fermentum, mattis sapien in, malesuada dolor. Praesent in risus in metus iaculis volutpat. Nam venenatis, magna eu dignissim vehicula, elit felis faucibus odio, eget interdum lorem justo eu elit. Nunc imperdiet
  neque ut mollis ultricies. Vestibulum viverra vel magna a dignissim. Nunc sed enim at massa commodo egestas. Nam id odio cursus, imperdiet magna nec, accumsan est. Aliquam vulputate tempor urna interdum rutrum. Nulla facilisi. Integer sed convallis
  justo. Sed a vestibulum dolor. Morbi nec dui a lectus viverra ultricies quis ut risus. Quisque eget hendrerit tortor. Morbi lobortis sagittis sodales. Quisque ultricies, diam ut ornare tincidunt, ante tellus ornare neque, eget faucibus erat enim nec
  arcu. Nam nec lobortis turpis. Curabitur molestie euismod tellus ac molestie. Proin malesuada suscipit suscipit. Nulla imperdiet mauris ullamcorper, scelerisque nibh lacinia, hendrerit justo. Curabitur venenatis odio lorem, ac bibendum sem rutrum eget.
  Sed nec finibus nisi, eu eleifend lacus. Vestibulum varius pulvinar ultrices. Suspendisse egestas nunc vel fringilla efficitur. Cras id eleifend arcu. Curabitur pellentesque scelerisque mi, sit amet ultrices tortor imperdiet a. Vestibulum ut dolor non
  est viverra rhoncus. Morbi ultrices dolor at erat pharetra, dignissim porta magna ultrices. Praesent sapien dui, sagittis eget tellus quis, tincidunt sollicitudin erat. Morbi commodo, dolor id mollis varius, lacus quam tincidunt odio, ut sagittis nisi
  massa sed quam. In eget est eget elit sollicitudin sollicitudin. Sed non nisl sed ipsum eleifend interdum ac quis enim. Nulla malesuada molestie sapien et fermentum. Nullam eu dui pretium, malesuada quam ut, hendrerit ipsum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus imperdiet erat a bibendum blandit. Nullam vitae mauris vel urna tempus hendrerit. Phasellus et odio est. Mauris a felis vel justo egestas dictum. Donec ultricies fermentum mattis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
  senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In ac nisl a libero scelerisque blandit. Nam neque tortor, bibendum eget augue et, accumsan faucibus quam. Aenean sed magna quis libero facilisis blandit ut at enim. Fusce faucibus porttitor arcu
  sit amet finibus. Maecenas fermentum nulla non erat cursus laoreet. Nullam erat arcu, volutpat ac ligula quis, tempus consectetur lorem. Aenean pellentesque felis a nisi viverra dictum. Curabitur at magna accumsan, scelerisque erat non, suscipit lorem.
  Aenean consectetur sem facilisis sem aliquet imperdiet. Aliquam mauris elit, finibus in tortor quis, cursus euismod urna. Integer vitae ultricies dui. Integer et nibh non nulla elementum finibus. Pellentesque ultricies dapibus dolor, consequat congue
  neque pharetra ac. Nam mollis risus nunc, ut accumsan diam semper quis. Aenean luctus magna ac tellus tempus auctor. Donec quis metus rhoncus, sollicitudin neque ac, maximus felis. Aliquam interdum mi ac sem gravida aliquet. Sed porttitor porttitor
  pharetra. Nunc diam sapien, consequat dapibus tincidunt in, pellentesque id est. Morbi in dui ac lorem interdum feugiat. Curabitur eget justo fermentum, mattis sapien in, malesuada dolor. Praesent in risus in metus iaculis volutpat. Nam venenatis, magna
  eu dignissim vehicula, elit felis faucibus odio, eget interdum lorem justo eu elit. Nunc imperdiet neque ut mollis ultricies. Vestibulum viverra vel magna a dignissim. Nunc sed enim at massa commodo egestas. Nam id odio cursus, imperdiet magna nec,
  accumsan est. Aliquam vulputate tempor urna interdum rutrum. Nulla facilisi. Integer sed convallis justo. Sed a vestibulum dolor. Morbi nec dui a lectus viverra ultricies quis ut risus. Quisque eget hendrerit tortor. Morbi lobortis sagittis sodales.
  Quisque ultricies, diam ut ornare tincidunt, ante tellus ornare neque, eget faucibus erat enim nec arcu. Nam nec lobortis turpis. Curabitur molestie euismod tellus ac molestie. Proin malesuada suscipit suscipit. Nulla imperdiet mauris ullamcorper, scelerisque
  nibh lacinia, hendrerit justo. Curabitur venenatis odio lorem, ac bibendum sem rutrum eget. Sed nec finibus nisi, eu eleifend lacus. Vestibulum varius pulvinar ultrices. Suspendisse egestas nunc vel fringilla efficitur. Cras id eleifend arcu. Curabitur
  pellentesque scelerisque mi, sit amet ultrices tortor imperdiet a. Vestibulum ut dolor non est viverra rhoncus. Morbi ultrices dolor at erat pharetra, dignissim porta magna ultrices. Praesent sapien dui, sagittis eget tellus quis, tincidunt sollicitudin
  erat. Morbi commodo, dolor id mollis varius, lacus quam tincidunt odio, ut sagittis nisi massa sed quam. In eget est eget elit sollicitudin sollicitudin. Sed non nisl sed ipsum eleifend interdum ac quis enim. Nulla malesuada molestie sapien et fermentum.
  Nullam eu dui pretium, malesuada quam ut, hendrerit ipsum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus imperdiet erat a bibendum blandit. Nullam vitae mauris vel urna tempus hendrerit. Phasellus et odio est. Mauris a felis vel justo
  egestas dictum. Donec ultricies fermentum mattis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In ac nisl a libero scelerisque blandit. Nam neque tortor, bibendum eget augue et, accumsan faucibus quam.
  Aenean sed magna quis libero facilisis blandit ut at enim. Fusce faucibus porttitor arcu sit amet finibus. Maecenas fermentum nulla non erat cursus laoreet. Nullam erat arcu, volutpat ac ligula quis, tempus consectetur lorem. Aenean pellentesque felis
  a nisi viverra dictum. Curabitur at magna accumsan, scelerisque erat non, suscipit lorem. Aenean consectetur sem facilisis sem aliquet imperdiet. Aliquam mauris elit, finibus in tortor quis, cursus euismod urna. Integer vitae ultricies dui. Integer
  et nibh non nulla elementum finibus. Pellentesque ultricies dapibus dolor, consequat congue neque pharetra ac. Nam mollis risus nunc, ut accumsan diam semper quis. Aenean luctus magna ac tellus tempus auctor. Donec quis metus rhoncus, sollicitudin neque
  ac, maximus felis. Aliquam interdum mi ac sem gravida aliquet. Sed porttitor porttitor pharetra. Nunc diam sapien, consequat dapibus tincidunt in, pellentesque id est. Morbi in dui ac lorem interdum feugiat. Curabitur eget justo fermentum, mattis sapien
  in, malesuada dolor. Praesent in risus in metus iaculis volutpat. Nam venenatis, magna eu dignissim vehicula, elit felis faucibus odio, eget interdum lorem justo eu elit. Nunc imperdiet neque ut mollis ultricies. Vestibulum viverra vel magna a dignissim.
  Nunc sed enim at massa commodo egestas. Nam id odio cursus, imperdiet magna nec, accumsan est. Aliquam vulputate tempor urna interdum rutrum. Nulla facilisi. Integer sed convallis justo. Sed a vestibulum dolor. Morbi nec dui a lectus viverra ultricies
  quis ut risus. Quisque eget hendrerit tortor. Morbi lobortis sagittis sodales. Quisque ultricies, diam ut ornare tincidunt, ante tellus ornare neque, eget faucibus erat enim nec arcu. Nam nec lobortis turpis. Curabitur molestie euismod tellus ac molestie.
  Proin malesuada suscipit suscipit. Nulla imperdiet mauris ullamcorper, scelerisque nibh lacinia, hendrerit justo. Curabitur venenatis odio lorem, ac bibendum sem rutrum eget. Sed nec finibus nisi, eu eleifend lacus. Vestibulum varius pulvinar ultrices.
  Suspendisse egestas nunc vel fringilla efficitur. Cras id eleifend arcu. Curabitur pellentesque scelerisque mi, sit amet ultrices tortor imperdiet a. Vestibulum ut dolor non est viverra rhoncus. Morbi ultrices dolor at erat pharetra, dignissim porta
  magna ultrices. Praesent sapien dui, sagittis eget tellus quis, tincidunt sollicitudin erat. Morbi commodo, dolor id mollis varius, lacus quam tincidunt odio, ut sagittis nisi massa sed quam. In eget est eget elit sollicitudin sollicitudin. Sed non
  nisl sed ipsum eleifend interdum ac quis enim. Nulla malesuada molestie sapien et fermentum. Nullam eu dui pretium, malesuada quam ut, hendrerit ipsum.

</p>
```

Comment: Thank you Chaska, it works perfectly :DDDD <3 Really Appreciate!!